# Replace character & leading 0s from the pipe delimited file in unix using sed or awk command

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have this below sample file abc.txt with more than 1000 rows

```
ABC00001|DEF00001|GHI00101|JKL01126|10|31|62|143|202301|01-01-2023
ABC00002|DEF00002|GHI00102|JKL01127|11|32|63|144|202301|01-01-2023
ABC00003|DEF00003|GHI00103|JKL01128|12|33|64|145|202301|01-01-2023
```

I need to remove character & leading 0s from the first four column of the file. The output should look like this

```
1|1|101|1126|10|31|62|143|202301|01-01-2023
2|2|102|1127|11|32|63|144|202301|01-01-2023
3|3|103|1128|12|33|64|145|202301|01-01-2023
```

How to achieve this using sed or awk command?

I am new to awk and I have used sed command multiple times for the single value but as the pipe delimiter file & doing operation on multiple columns I have never done it.

I tried echo `ABC00001 | cut -c 4- | sed 's/^0*//'` which gives me result 1. I dont know how to incorporate this in script for all the columns.

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Hint: `awk -F '|' '{for (i=1; i<=4; i++) { sub(..., "", $i) }1' abc.txt >new.txt`

Comment: I tried using sed to remove the characters & leading 0s from each column but I am new to awk & I dont know how to use for the columns wise replacement.
I tried like echo ABC00001 | cut -c 4- | sed 's/^0*//'. this will give 1 as a result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your best attempt and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @ImSahil Would `sed 's/\(^\||\)[A-Z]\{1,\}0*/\1/g'` do what you want?`

Comment: @Biffen : Yes its working. Thank you but This command will replace all the characters from the file & also all the leading 0s from the file. Can we do something in sed which will only replace character & leading 0s on the 1st four columns only?

Comment: @ImSahil Ah, I missed that. Then I’d go with `awk`. tripleee’s hint above is a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABC00001|DEF00001|GHI00101|JKL01126|10|31|62|143|202301|01-01-2023
ABC00002|DEF00002|GHI00102|JKL01127|11|32|63|144|202301|01-01-2023
ABC00003|DEF00003|GHI00103|JKL01128|12|33|64|145|202301|01-01-2023
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=4;i+=1){sub(/^[[:alpha:]]+0*/,"",$i)};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1|1|101|1126|10|31|62|143|202301|01-01-2023
2|2|102|1127|11|32|63|144|202301|01-01-2023
3|3|103|1128|12|33|64|145|202301|01-01-2023
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that pipe character is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`). I use `for` loop to apply following change to columns from 1st to 4th (inclusive): replace one-or-more (`+`) leading (`^`) alphabetic characters (`[[:alpha:]]`) followed by zero character (`0`) repeated zero-or-more times (`*`) using empty string i.e. delete them. After this is done I `print` line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: `awk 'gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+0*/,"")' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\|/&\n/4;h;s/\n.*//;s/(\|?)[^0-9]+0+/\1/g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Insert a newline as a delimiter for the first four fields and make a copy in the hold space.

Remove all but the first four fields from the current line.

Remove the leading non-numeric and zeroes from each of the remaining fields.

Append the copy with the newline delimiter.

Remove everything between the newlines which prepends the ameliorated fields to the unchanged fields.

---

An couple of alternatives:

```
sed -E 's/\|/\n/4g;s/^/\|/;s/(\|)[^0-9]*0*/\1/g;s/.//;y/\n/|/' file

sed 'y/|/\n/
     s#.*#bash -c "sed -E '\''1,4{s/[^0-9]//g;s/^0+//}'\'' <<<$'\''&'\''"#e
     y/\n/|/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z]*0*//g' file
1|1|101|1126|10|31|62|143|202301|01-01-2023
2|2|102|1127|11|32|63|144|202301|01-01-2023
3|3|103|1128|12|33|64|145|202301|01-01-2023
```